# Manage access to documents on per-user basis for Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

Say I have `users` collection in my Firestore database and user documents should only be visible to a specific set of other users (e.g. connected users on a social media app).

Similarly to the example in the docs for about [Secure data access for users and groups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access) I can use an array `visibleTo` which contains user ids of connected users. I can then fetch all user documents that should be visible to any specific client by using an `array-contains` query like so:

```
firestore.collection('users').where('visibleTo', 'array-contains', ownUserID).get()
```

However, this also means that for one each clients know with which other users their contacts are connected to since this array is fetched to clients as part of the user document and second this can generate unnecessary traffic.

For reference consider this example document:

```
{
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    visibleTo: ['userID0001', 'userID0002', 'userID0003', ...] // imagine 200 entries here
}
```

How could I use Firestore to achieve this functionality of fetching only 'connected' users / contacts without actually fetching the `visibleTo` array?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this field visibleTo is in a location where the user does not have access (new collection path)

**Example:**

Doc location : /accessData/{userId}/visibility

and data could be

```
{
    visibleTo: ['userID0001', 'userID0002', 'userID0003', ...]
}
```

the above collection /accessData no one has access to only admin can access.

Then make sure you move the read access logic to the Firestore security rules and not the fetch logic in the application. In the Firestore security rules fetch the data from this path and identify if they can view or not /accessData/{userId}/visibility

Comment: I have this logic also in the security rules; however, I also need it on the client side since I exactly want to fetch the user documents that are visible to any client. I cannot query using fields in other documents and also security rules cannot act as filters. What am I missing?